# Rails Youtube_it gem background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, delayed-job

I'm fairly new to Rails and I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2 application and I've integrated the Youtube_it gem seen here https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it.  The gem works fine and I'm able to upload the video to youtube, but it takes a while to process the video.  I would like to be able to run that as a background job and redirect the user to the thank you page I have created.

I'm not sure where to call the delay method.  I would like to call the delay method and then have the user redirect to the page_path('thank-you') page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've searched all over for an answer.

VideosController
    def upload
    @video = Video.create(params[:video])

```
if @video
  @upload_info = Video.delay.token_form(params[:video], save_video_new_video_url(video_id:     @video.id))
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "/videos/new" }
  end
end
end



def save_video
@video = Video.find(params[:video_id])

if params[:status].to_i == 200
  @video.update_attributes(youtube_id: params[:id].to_s, is_complete: true, user_id: current_user.id, approved: false)
  Video.delete_incomplete_videos
else
  Video.delete_video(@video)
end
#redirect_to videos_path, notice: "video successfully uploaded"
redirect_to page_path('thank-you')
end
```

Here is my controller.

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :upload, :save_video, :destroy]

def index
  if params[:category]
    Video.yt_session
    @videos = Video.approved.where(category_id: params[:category])
  else
    Video.yt_session
    @videos = Video.approved
  end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @videos }
end
end

def show
 @video = Video.find(params[:id])

 respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @video }
 end
end

def new
@video =Video.new
@categories = Category.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @video }
end
end


def upload
@video = Video.create(params[:video])

if @video
  @upload_info = Video.token_form(params[:video], save_video_new_video_url(video_id: @video.id))
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "/videos/new" }
  end
end
end




def save_video
@video = Video.find(params[:video_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @video.update_attributes(:youtube_id => params[:id].to_s, :is_complete =>     true,:user_id=>current_user.id,:approved=>false)
    format.html { redirect_to page_path('thank-you') }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  else
    format.html { Video.delete_video(@video) }
    format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def destroy
@video = Video.find(params[:id])

if Video.delete_video(@video)
  flash[:notice] = "Video deleted."
else
  flash[:error] = "We were unable to delete this video."
end
redirect_to videos_path
end


def vote_up
@video = Video.find(params[:id])
@video.update_attribute(:votes_up, (@video.votes_up.to_i + 1))
redirect_to @video
end


protected
def collection
@videos ||= end_of_association_chain.completes
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use background workers to do that using the like of [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), but personally speaking I prefer to use Resque/beanstalkd/RabbitMQ since I can run multiple workers, concurrently.

To make your life even easier, you just try Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).

You will move your worker logic to some worker.

Include Sidekiq to your Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq'
```

At your controller add something like:

```
VideoSaverWorker.perform_async(@video.id)
```

The VideoSaverWorker must look something like:

```
class VideoSaverWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "high"

  def perform(video_id)
    video = Video.find(video_id)
    .....
    .....
  end
end
```

Please note using this you will do the work at a background thread, but it wont redirect you to the related page.

You will need to do some workarounds, something like periodically refrishing the page till you see the changes at your view html page, or maybe you can push the changes to your webpage using Faye or Node.js.

Comment: I already have tried to integrate the delayed_jobs gem.  I'm just not sure where to call the .delay method to have it delay the upload and redirect to the thank-you page.  I edited my question with my controller.